# Guardar Cuestionario (C#) en Word o en SQL server

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente cuestionario, el cual realice en C#, es una prueba que se realiza a las personas de nuevo ingreso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me gustaría seria guardar todo el documento en Word, digamos para tener un respaldo de cada persona que realiza la prueba, para así poder imprimirlo en un momento que se requiera ver los resultados de cierta persona.

Espero haber sido explicito con lo que pretendo hacer.

Saludos Gracias.

Comment: Por que los quieres mandar a word ? 
puedes fácilmente salvar un archivo txt con streamwrite 
pero si quieres hacer un archivo de word tendras que utlizar las librerias de interop de office 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: Bueno Realmente no me importa mandarlo, solamente poder almacenarlo como un archivo y así poder imprimirlo. Saludos

Comment: Aquí hay un articulo de como crear archivos, solo te recomendaria algun metodo de nombramiento para evitar duplicidad o que tus documentos sean sobre escritos, tambien necesitaras algo de lógica si quieres crear directorios y asegurarte que los directorios que necesitas ya están creados o no. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file en especifico la linea importante que necesitas para transformar tu string a un documento es: System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", text); y luego con un simple Proce

Comment: Todo esto debe ir en una base de datos. y los reportes hacerlo con una herramienta de reporting.

Comment: Por eso se me hace mas fácil crear un archivo, que se pueda copiar digamos exactamente la aplicación a Word y de ahí poder imprimirla.

Comment: Con Reportview se podria? saludos.

Comment: aqui te dejo otra referencia que tal vez te sea de utilidad 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-print-a-windows-form

el metodo importante es "CaptureScreen" pero en lugar de imprimir, debes de guardar el memoryimage como un bmp . para eso debes utilizar memoryimage.save("c:\blablabla.bmp");

Answer (score 0):

Hola muchas Gracias a todos por sus respuesta, logre pasar a un documento de Word, mediante el siguiente codigo.

```html
object ObjMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            word.Application objWord = new word.Application();
            string ruta = Application.StartupPath + @"\Examen Karosso.docx";
            object parametro = ruta;
            word.Document objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(parametro, ObjMiss);
            object fecha1 = "Fecha";
            word.Range Fech = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref fecha1).Range;
            Fech.Text = dateTimePicker1.Text;
            object rango1 = Fech;
            objWord.Visible = true;
            objDoc.Bookmarks.Add("fecha", ref rango1);
            objDoc.Activate();
            objWord.Selection.Font.Color = word.WdColor.wdColorBlack;
            objWord.Selection.TypeText(Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text + "\r\n"));
```

El Cual Me crea un documento en Word para poder almacenarlo y mandarlo a imprimir.
Saludos y Gracias.